# How to close RemoteApp connection from client side?

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

Sometimes I have problem with printer, and I must log-off my user from RemoteApp server, but I do not have access to this server.

When I close RemoteApp, connection will not be disconnected and wait my action. When I disable wireless adapter, connection will be disconnect.

Is it possible to write script for disconnection RemoteApp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple: I can kill process `mstsc.exe`.